# How do I get the version number and build of the application from Jenkins?

Tags: c#, jenkins, build

I have an application on c # that is built on Jenkins. The build numbers go in order from 1 to 23 at the moment.

On the About window, I need to display the version number of the application along with the build number. Manually edit each time AssemblyVersion is not a variant.)

I tried to install `[assembly: AssemblyVersion ("1.0.0. *")]`, but the build number was 25137, although on the Jenkens itself with the numbering everything is fine:

[image]

Can you please tell how to get the number of the current build of Jenkins?

Comment: Do you need current build number of Jenkins job or build number of the application built with the job?

Comment: @GoranĆojanović,  the current build number of Jenkins job. That is, now it should be 1.0.0.23 and next time - 1.0.0.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins defines various [environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) for each executions. The one you want is most likely BUILD_NUMBER.

You will need to write this into the file at build time, I see that NAnt has a task for this, if you're using NAnt: [asminfo](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/asminfo.html).